# UITextContentType* not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikit

I am using `UITextContentType` GivenName/FamilyName on `UITextfield` subclass to allow user to quickly fill up their personal details in sign up form.

For some reason when ever user tap on the suggested name in suggestion bar above keyboard, it is not filling up the `textfield`. Instead it is filling the single space.

I have checked with the `textfield` delegate,

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

In that also I am getting a single space in new test.

Anyone faced the same issue and know the solution of this issue?

[image]

Comment: As I remember, when you tap on suggestion, `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method is called twice. One for adding single space and one for adding suggestion text. You should check again. It's better if you can show your code.

Comment: Did you find the answer for this ?? Im also facing the same issue ??? @piyush hirpara

Answer (score 0):

The Delegate method is possible what is causing the issue

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

It is a strange behavior
The delegate method will be called once first with empty string. Then if the method returns false nothing else happens.

But if you return true it is called again with the proper replacement string

Reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55721707/1463518

Here is a workaround

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.isEmpty || string == " " {
       defer {
         if let text = textField.text, let textRange = Range(range, in: text) {
       textField.text = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: "")
         }
       }
       return true
    }
    // do your stuff
    return false
}
```