# shouldChangeCharactersIn Combined with Suggested Text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` and am using the delegate method `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`

The fields here have the ability to display suggested text (e.g. name). The problem comes in when a suggestion is taken versus when the user types in single letters. If a suggestion is taken (e.g. Tom) the delegate method fires but `string` just contains a blank space " ". This causes validation failure since it is assumed the user is typing in an empty space when reality they selected a full word.

How can we use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` to check text entry but still allow for the use of suggested text?

Comment: Is `string` " " (blank space) or "" (empty string). I believe it is an empty string in the case of backspace. Also can you show your validation code?

Comment: The string is a blank space as in " " not an empty string. Validation doesn't matter. The issue is that the string returned by the method is a blank space making any further work on it moot. So pretending it's an empty method how would one deal with the selection of suggested text if the result looks like a single blank space?

Comment: String returned by the method? Which method?

Comment: Sorry, poorly worded. The `string` in the function call itself.

Comment: Ok. Hmm.. how does autocomplete work exactly? Can you share the code for that? How does selecting a word in suggested text set the word to the text field?

Comment: There is no code. This is a feature of a text field which can be enabled in the interface builder.  In the IB you can say that a text field is a "name" field as an example. Then when the user taps in that field, Apple presents names just above the keyboard. So this something you get for free. However, as I am finding, the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` is fired even though this is a whole word. So it is conflated with the user typing individual letters.

Comment: Any update yet.?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - Unfortunately no. I needed to pursue other paths in order to move forward. Hope to come back to this later.

Comment: I'm fighting with the same problem. News?

Comment: @AlessioZapBoerio - Unfortunately no. I took an alternate path. I did come back to look a this but I cannot find a reason the method fires twice.

Comment: @C6Silver my ugly workaround for the moment is create an Action on textfield did change event. Inside it I'm doing all filter and trimming stuff. It's ugly but at least I can manage it :/

Answer (score 8):

If user uses suggestion, `shouldChangeCharactersIn` fires up to two times: first with single whitespace. Then if the method returns `false` nothing else happens. But if the method returns `true` then `shouldChangeCharactersIn` fires ones more with suggested string + whitespace at the end of it. So if you want to use keyboard suggestions you have to allow whitespaces and (if needed) remove them later somehow depending on your demands. One way is using `defer` like this (not tested, but to give you an idea):

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  if string == " " {
    defer {
      if let text = textField.text, let textRange = Range(range, in: text) {
    textField.text = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: "")
      }
    }
    return true
  }

  // rest of the code for input filtering

  return false
}
```

Comment: That's very strange behavior from Apple.